# How to resize NotifyIcon?

Tags: c#, wpf

```
_notifyIcon = new NotifyIcon();
_notifyIcon.Icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
_notifyIcon.BalloonTipClosed += (s, e) => _notifyIcon.Visible = false;      
_notifyIcon.Visible = true;
_notifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(3000, "Title here", "Message displayed.",
                ToolTipIcon.None);
```

If I change the last line to `TooltipIcon.Warning` or anything else (Info, etc.) It's going to show a big picture like this:

[image: See here]

But in my case I'm going to assume that the reason the picture I'm getting in the notification is so small, is because it's taking its original size (since it's an icon). So, how to resize it?

Comment: Hmm, no, that is quite doubtful.  It is not 2015 anymore.  I'd have to guess that got this image from somewhere else that demonstrated a bug in an early Win10 release.  Or you backdated the clock to avoid expiring a beta release.  Current Win10 releases show a large icon with the letter i in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

.ico files can contain multiple different images of different resolutions. It seems like you need to add the appropriate resolutions to your existing file so that it displays the appropriate size ... See the following link for more information ... https://superuser.com/questions/491180/how-do-i-embed-multiple-sizes-in-an-ico-file

If you use visual studio, it has a built in icon editor that supports embedding multiple resolutions.